# Save in exisiting folder

Tags: excel, vba, save

I want this code to always save the pdf in the same location as the file.
If I do not manual resave   this file before running the code, the pdf ends up in a different location.

```vb
    Sub Save_Mappe_As_pdf()
                       
    'turns off screen updating & display alerts & etc to go faster
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       
    'declares the variable mappe based upon text in a cell
    Dim mappe As String
    mappe = Worksheets("Erfassen").Range("g2")
       
    'declares the variable saveLocation the same as this excel document
    Dim saveLocation As String
    saveLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'saves the pdf in the same folder as the recently saved mappe

    'declares & selects the variable sheetArray aka it selects which sheets will be exported as a pdf
    Dim sheetArray As Variant
    sheetArray = Array("Druck", "Infozettel", "Kontrolle", "Beschriftungszettel")
    Sheets(sheetArray).Select
    
    'exports the selected sheets as a pdf
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=mappe, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    'Worksheets("Erfassen").Range("b8").Activate  'moves to the erfassen sheet
    Dim eingabe_sheet As Worksheet
    Set eingabe_sheet = Sheets("Eingabe")
    eingabe_sheet.Activate

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

I tried workbook.activate before the savelocation code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you define folder first by setting up the mappe variable. After this you use another variable to store the saveLocation. Be sure which one you are using as Filename argument when exporting as PDF.

Before saving the PDF-file the `saveLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Path` returns e.g. C:\SomePath. Now what happens is that the file gets saved one folder level up with the same name as the folder C:\SomePath.pdf.

Rather, when exporting, you should define both the path and the valid filename (e.g. the Excel-filename itself without the extension .xlsm). Something like `Filename:=saveLocation & "\" & Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)`

Hope this helps.